# fatal exception Error while firing kafka server

Tags: apache-kafka

I just installed tha kafka and run  the zookeeper but cant run the kafka server with that comand

C:\kafka>.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat config/server.properties

CONSOLE MESSAGE:
C:\kafka>.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat config/server.properties
[2024-03-25 14:53:21,539] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2024-03-25 14:53:21,748] INFO Setting -D jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true to disable client-initiated TLS renegotiation (org.apache.zookeeper.common.X509Util)
[2024-03-25 14:53:21,779] ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception (kafka.Kafka$)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.kafka.coordinator.group.Group.GroupType.CLASS¦C
at java.base/java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:273)
at org.apache.kafka.coordinator.group.Group$GroupType.valueOf(Group.java:29)
at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.$anonfun$groupCoordinatorRebalanceProtocols$2(KafkaConfig.scala:2020)
at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedIterableOps.map(StrictOptimizedIterableOps.scala:100)
at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedIterableOps.map$(StrictOptimizedIterableOps.scala:87)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.map(ArrayBuffer.scala:43)
at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.(KafkaConfig.scala:2020)
at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.(KafkaConfig.scala:1639)
at kafka.Kafka$.buildServer(Kafka.scala:71)
at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:90)
at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)

C:\kafka>

I just installed tha kafka and run  the zookeeper but cant run the kafka server with that comand